# Bash nth command substitution?

Tags: bash

I know that

`$ ^previous^replacement^`

will substitute "previous" with "replacement" in the **last** command in bash shell. How to substitute a nth command in the history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example:

```
!n:s/previous/replacement/
```

See the [HISTORY EXPANSION](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction) section of the man page for full details.